# Angular select visible element based on some value

Tags: angular, angular9, ng-switch

I get a list of items from a service as an (observable) array. The elements in the have a `type: string;` field, which I intend to use as an indicator for selecting different components to display. When I don't have a widget for a type yet, I want to display the type as a string.

### Versions

When I forgot something, let me know, and I will add it.

| module | version |
| --- | --- |
| node | v14.2.0 |
| Angular CLI | 9.1.6 |
| npm | 6.14.4 |
| @angular/core | ~9.1.7 |

### What I got so far

#### The component template I'm using

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="8" rowHeight="1:1" class="grid">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let widget of widgets |async">
    <mat-grid-tile class="grid-item">
      <div [ngSwitch]="widget.type">
        <app-light-toggle [widget]="widget" *ngSwitchWhen="light"></app-light-toggle>
        <div *ngSwitchDefault>
          {{widget.type}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </ng-container>
</mat-grid-list>
```

#### The widget class with the field:

```js
export class Widget {
  // other fields left out, because irrelevant.
  type: string;

  constructor(type :string) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```

#### What I would expect

Then the `type` value is equal to `light` select the first case, which would display the widget for `light`. When the `type` is equal to anything else, display the `type` variable in the tile

#### What I get

[image: The result]

### Notes

- When removing the `ng-switch-default` `div`, both `tiles` show the `app-light-toggle`.
- I found several different notations for the switch syntax and am rather lost on which one to use

  - [NgSwitch](https://v9.angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) results in an error, which personally tells me nothing (`ERROR Error: No provider for TemplateRef`)

    - Does this mean, I can provide templates somewhere?
    - If so, where do I do this? I can't seem to find anything regrading a template store or anything in the documentation
  - [ng_ng-switch](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-switch.asp) does seem to do something, but does not behave as I would expect (see explanation above)

### Updates

1. I added an asterisk before `ngSwitchWhen`, which fixed the template error, I think. But still I get the wrong option selected.
2. I found out, that both elements get rendered on top of each other.
3. Added the angular version
4. Added Solution
5. Moved solution to stackblitz

### Solution

The Solution Provided by @Poul Kruijt in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66940798/2043252) answer did it for me. I was using the wrong directive and did not use quotes in the value. A simplified stackbliz version can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yixikd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: which angular are you using? your tag says angularjs, is that so? if not and it's Angular 2+, it should be `*ngSwitchCase` instead of `*ngSwitchWhen`

Comment: In the angular.json the version says 1. I'm not to sure though. I just started developing with the version I installed when I last used it.

Comment: @angular/core version is your Angular version

Comment: thanks, added the version (is 9 correct?) the versioning of angular is a little opaque to me.

Comment: I guess current implementation is wrong designed. I would put all logic with `switchCase` in the `app-light-toggle` component

Comment: so basically a base component, which selects the actual component I want to show in code? Do you  by any chance have a resource, that I can use as guide?

Comment: I think this guide can come in handy for you https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and report back :)

Comment: It would be better if you provided https://stackblitz.com/ sample of your application

Comment: will do.  thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's called `ngSwitchCase`. Second, You should put quotes around your `*ngSwitchCase` assignment, otherwise it will look for a component variable named `light`:

```
*ngSwitchCase="'light'"
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not help. I added an update (2)

Comment: @Wr4thon your version still shows ngSwitchWhen instead of ngSwitchCase. Can you create a stackblitz with your issues?

Comment: oh my god, I'm dumb. Thank you this helped. I will update the code in the question.